# PHP Check if username is set

Tags: php

All im trying to do is see if the username is set in the cookies, ive tried `isset()` and `empty()` with no luck. Also i tried `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['username']` and `$username` with those functions and the php does nothing no matter if the cookie username is set or not. Web pages are fake, but i use real ones that i know work in my code.

```
 $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['username'] = $username;

 if(isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['username']))
 {
 header("page2.html"); 
 }

 else {
 header("page1.html"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `header('Location: page2.html')` and `header('Location: page1.html')` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
   header('Location: page2.html');
}else{
   header('Location: page1.html');
}
```

Comment: thanks i dont know what is diffrent here from what ive been trying but this worked! thanks

Comment: you do not have the header set correctly in your own code however Robus does (you missed the location bit)

Answer (score 2):

Uh...

```
isset($_COOKIE['username']);
```

Also, you're using set_cookie to define cookies, correct? (Prolly a stupid question, sorry.)

Edit: Yeah, nevermind, the "Location: " header suggestion Daniel mentioned should do the trick (and the HTTP_*_VARS are deprecated since PHP 5, but I decided not to mention that :P).

Comment: does it make a difference? trying it now.

Comment: @FreezeWarp Also, if you feel like adding this to your answer, `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php